# PHP - Submit HTML form with missing name attribute

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

I have the following HTML form (including JavaScript) from an external website that I'm trying to automate login for.

```
<form name="autologin" method="POST" action="https://post.website.com"></form>
<script language="JavaScript">
document.autologin.submit();
</script>
```

with inputs

```
<input type="hidden" name="Z" value="0,0">
<input style="font-size: 11px;" type="submit" value="Logon">
```

How do I submit this form programmatically using PHP, if it the second input has a missing name?

My code so far:

```
$url = 'https://post.website.com';

$request = new HTTP_REQUEST2($url, HTTP_REQUEST2::METHOD_POST);
$mainPageRequest = array(
'Z' => '0,0',
'' => 'Logon'   //  <---- What goes here since it's missing a name?
);

$request->addPostParameter($mainPageRequest);
$request->send();
```

Comment: You could give it a name? call it 'login', 'submit', etc ?

Comment: How do you get the form` from external site ?

Comment: The second input is just the submit button without a name, therefore it's irrelevant.

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase the question, a little more description would help to understand the scenario.

Comment: This is not my form, so I can't change the name. I'm scraping a website and need to submit this form using PHP. To get the form from the external site, I'm just viewing the HTML source of the website in Chrome. Any clues on how to submit a POST request with a missing name attribute in submit?

Comment: But what is the problem? In which situation do you need that button to have a name? You can submit a form without all the buttons having names... Wait, do you have more than one `submit` button and do you need to simulate a click on one of them?

Comment: @MarkKennedy _What goes here since it's missing a name?_... remove that entry from your array, it's not being used by the original form. The form data will only contain the parameter for "Z" when submitted, you do not need to mimic the submit button in this instance.

Comment: @MrLister I only have one submit. How do I simulate the click without a reference to the name attribute?

Comment: @Scuzzy The value of the submit must be "Logon" at the time the form is sent, correct? ..Or are you saying I don't need to fill that value in and just send the POST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inputs without names are not submitted at all. If submitting a form in the normal way (by clicking the button), only those inputs that have names will be transferred; the others are simply ignored.
You can test for yourself by putting some inputs, with and without names in a form and using `method="get"`, so that the submitted data ends up visually in the location bar.

So the answer to the question "What goes here since it's missing a name?" is: nothing.

```
$mainPageRequest = array(
  'Z' => '0,0'
);
```